# "will not long go unsold to" meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrases, double-negation

What does "will not go unsold to" mean in the following sentence?

> The King of Portugal, Lord of Spices, has set... prices just as he pleases, for pepper, which, at any cost, no matter how dear, *will not long go unsold to* the Germans.

Source: *Bound Together: How Traders, Preachers, Adventurers, and Warriors Shaped Globalization*, by Nayan Chanda
Google book link--- http://goo.gl/YPngmK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like a double negative. Meaning *Will be soon sold to Germans.*
not long = soon (shortly)
not go unsold = will sell

Comment: I wouldn't read "not long" as "soon", but as "not for a long time". _The pepper well not remain (in an) unsold (state) for a long time_. And that unsold state is further defined as _unsold to the Germans_.